# Angular DataTable : On Button Click to load JSON data to the DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

Angular Datatable : Click to load json data to the datatable. Have json data in one variable and one button, and Once click on button, need to pass the json data and populate datatable. If button click, JSON data is not populated in datatable. Below code I tried, any issue pls suggest

```
ngOnInit(): void {}

  loadJsonData() {
    alert("inside");
    const jsondata = [
      { id: 860, firstName: "Superman", lastName: "Yoda" },
      { id: 861, firstName: "xyz", lastName: "Abc" }
    ];
    this.dtOptions[2] = {
      data: jsondata,
      columns: [
        {
          data: "id"
        },
        {
          data: "firstName"
        },
        {
          data: "lastName"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-pr9l1h?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: the reason is the datatable is loaded on pageload and loadJsonData() is not updating the  UI. I have updated Stackblitz to add fix.

Comment: Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-ryrtdm?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: did it work as per your expectation

Comment: yes Rajat, very thanks for the help.